# How can I get the specific tile in a collision with a Tilemap?

Tags: collision-detection, tiles, tilemap, godot

I am developing a simple platformer, I have three types of tiles right now:

- **Floor:** does nothing on collision.
- **Bad:** makes the player lose the game.
- **Good:** makes the player beat the game.

I am trying to detect the collision with this code I found:

```
extends RigidBody2D

func _process(delta):
    var tile = get_parent().get_node("TileMap").get_cellv(get_parent().get_node("TileMap").world_to_map(position))
    print(tile)
```

The `tile` variable is supposed to contain the identifier of the type of tile the player is touching, but it doesn't, it always returns -1 (No exception or error, just -1).

I believe returning -1 means it isn't touching any tile, but it is.

This is using Godot 3.0 stable.

What am I missing?

Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to make it work, I am not sure if this is the best possible solution but it works:

```
extends RigidBody2D

func _integrate_forces(state):
    var tilemap= get_parent().get_node("TileMap");  
    for i in range(get_colliding_bodies().size()):
        var tile_pos = tilemap.world_to_map(state.get_contact_local_position(i))
        var tile = tilemap.get_cellv(tile_pos)
```

This function is inside my player script. `var tile` will contain the type id of each colliding tile.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but in my case i was raycasting and found a neat set of key value pairs to my aid:

```
var result = space_state.intersect_ray(origin, get_global_mouse_position(), [self, owner]);
```

If the colliding object is a tilemap, there is a entry called 'metadata' which contains the coordinates (in terms of tilemap coordinates) of that tile which collided with the ray.